# second or third time a symbol appears

Tags: php, regex

In PHP

```
$regex = '/ ([$]) *(\d+(:?.\d+)?)/';
preg_match($regex, $str, $matches);

print_r($matches[2]);
```

This regex gives me the first occurence of a number that follows the first `$` sign in a web page.

Now I want a regex that would give me the number after the second `$` sign and maybe the third too.

Comment: Don’t answer to your own question if it’s not a answer but a comment on someone other’s answer. Use the comment function unter each answer to write a comment to that answer or update your question.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is the *[preg_match_all](http://php.net/preg_match_all)* function.

```
preg_match_all('/([$])*(\d+(:?.\d+)?)/', $str, $result, [flags]);
```

*$result* contains all matches in an array in the order specified by *flags*.

Answer (score 0):

preg_match only matches the first occurrence of the regex, if you use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/preg_match_all), you'll get the array which you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Second result should be $result[1](https://www.php.net/preg_match_all), third $result[2] and so on.

Edit*

You don't want to actually use [flags], but one of the "flags" found [here](https://www.php.net/preg_match_all).

You probably want something along the lines of:

```
<?php
// The \\2 is an example of backreferencing. This tells pcre that
// it must match the second set of parentheses in the regular expression
// itself, which would be the ([\w]+) in this case. The extra backslash is
// required because the string is in double quotes.
$html = "<b>bold text</b><a href=howdy.html>click me</a>";

preg_match_all("/(<([\w]+)[^>]*>)(.*)(<\/\\2>)/", $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($matches as $val) {
    echo "matched: " . $val[0] . "\n";
    echo "part 1: " . $val[1] . "\n";
    echo "part 2: " . $val[3] . "\n";
    echo "part 3: " . $val[4] . "\n\n";
}
?>
```